# What are these %(...)s strings in fail2ban's jail.conf file, and how do they work?

Tags: security, configuration, fail2ban

In setting up `fail2ban` there are what appear to be variables at the top of the `jail.conf` that look like this:

```
mytime=300
.
.
.
[ssh]
bantime=%(mytime)s
```

Or in this more complicated form like this:

```
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"].
```

#### Questions

- How do these work and what's going on with them?
- Specifically what's the deal with the `%(...string...)s`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the rules that are included with `fail2ban` you'll notice that they use these variables to make things neater and more parameterized. For example in the included `jail.conf` they've used them to make general action rules that they can then use when defining the various jails.

#### Example

Here are some basic variables at the top.

```
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in
# jail.{conf,local,d/*} configuration files.
destemail = root@localhost

# Sender email address used solely for some actions
sender = root@localhost

# Default protocol
protocol = tcp

# Ports to be banned
# Usually should be overridden in a particular jail
port = 0:65535
```

These variables are then used in other variables to construct some basic actions.

```
# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define
# action_* variables. Can be overridden globally or per
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-multiport

# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
```

Notice here that they're constructing a general purpose action called, `action_` which is made using other variables, such as, `%(banaction)s`, `%(port)s`, `%(protocol)s, etc.

From the `man jail.conf` man page:

> Using Python "string interpolation" mechanisms, other definitions are allowed and can later 
>   be used within other definitions as %(name)s. For example.
>
> ```
>          baduseragents = IE|wget
>          failregex = useragent=%(baduseragents)s
> ```

So the `%(...)s` are part of the Python language. If you search for them you'll eventually find this page from the Python language's specification, specifically this section titled: [5.6.2. String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). There is an example on this page:

```
>>> print '%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.' % \
...       {"language": "Python", "number": 2}
Python has 002 quote types.
```

The `%(...string...)s` is called a string formatting or interpolation operator in Python. The `s` at the end of the `%(...string...)` is a flag, specifying that any Python objects that may be passed to it, get converted to strings. From the link I referenced, there's a table with all the flags allowed:

[image: ss#1]

The `%` specifies where you want the specifier to begin, and the `(...string...)` is what Python variable we want to have expanded here.